# Arial Narrow not available as a 'local' font

Tags: css, fonts

I need to replace a existing font-face with **Ariel Narrow**. However the below code does not work.

```
@font-face {
font-family: site-generic-font;
src: local("Arial Narrow");
font-weight: 700;}
```

**Ariel Narrow** Is not being picked up on my Computer. The alternative below works so why won't the "`local`" code work?

`font-family: Arial Narrow;`

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: MyArialNarrow;
    src: local("Arial Narrow");
  }


div { font-size:30px; }


.c2 { font-family: myFirstFont2; font-weight: 700; }
.c3 { font-family: Arial Narrow; font-weight: 700; }
```

```html
<div class="c2">I am Arial Narrow.</div>
<div class="c3">I am Arial Narrow.</div>
```

Comment: What makes you think this would work? Do you _have_ Arial Narrow installed? How did you verify that? Also, `@font-face` are instructions to the CSS engine for binding specific individual typefaces, so unless you set up specific binding for that `font-weight:700` instruction, using page CSS that picks the font you told the CSS engine to use for default weights won't get used when you tell it to use a _different_ weight.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for your reply. 
Ignore the 'font-weight' in this conversation please. It is not part of the topic.

Arrow Narrow is installed as part of Windows10 and mac. The above test should show font-family: Arial Narrow; works. If font-family picks up Arial Narrow then it must be present on your device. However local("Arial Narrow") does not work on Chrome Windows 10. 

To make things even more strange, if you use the following Firefox Windows 10 then the result is opposite. 'local' works but font-family, does not.

Comment: Note that Arial Narrow [does not come with Windows 10 at all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Microsoft_Windows). It might get installed along with certain productivity software (and then probably specifically Office, which has a bunch more fonts from the Arial families), but don't rely on it if you need to support windows and mac users. That said, I can't reproduce this with any font name. http://jsbin.com/tiyumeziru/edit?html,css,output does the right thing every time, as long as you type the correct font name.